# CharField is not rendering in template - Django

Tags: django

I have a date of birth field in my model but why it's not showing up in the template when I render it? The `date_of_birth` is inside `Teacher` model. And Do you have any good idea on `date_of_birth` field? Because right now I'm using charfield for that so I need to convert the `DateInput` to string so that I can add it into `charfield`.

here is my models.py

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    date_of_birth = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    teacher_type = models.CharField(max_length=50

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email
```

my forms.py

```
class TeacherRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    date_attr = {'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'dateofbirth-register', 'type': 'date'}
    
    date_of_birth = forms.DateField(widget = forms.DateInput(attrs=date_attr))
    teacher_type = forms.ChoiceField(label=_('Teacher Type'), choices=type_choice

    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['date_of_birth', 'teacher_type']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.is_teacher = True
        user.save()
        teacher = Teacher.objects.create(user=user)
        teacher.date_of_birth += str(self.cleaned_data.get('date_of_birth'))
        teacher.teacher_type += self.cleaned_data.get('teacher_type')
        return user
```

views.py

```
@login_required
@teacher_required
def teacherInfoView(request):
    template_name = "attendance/content/teacher/teacher_info.html"
    teacher_info = Teacher.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    context = {'teacher_info': teacher_info}
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

template

```
{% for info in teacher_info %}
      <!-- firstname -->
<div class="row">
 <div class="ml-5 mr-auto">
   <h5>Name : {{ info.user.first_name }} {{ info.user.last_name }}</h5>
 </div>
 <div class="ml-5">
   <h5>Email : {{ info.user.email }}</h5>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <div class="ml-5">
  <h5>Date Of Birth : {{ info.date_of_birth }}</h5>
 </div>
 <div class="ml-5">
  <h5>Gender : {{ info.user.gender }}</h5>
 </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Add a `breakpoint()` right before you return the rendered view to check if you have the `date_of_birth` key in the `teacher_info` at all. I think there is something wrong with the conversion of `DateField` and then `DateInput` into `CharField` but can't be sure.

Comment: I also have another field which is `teacher_type`. It's a `charField` and I also can't render it to template. let me update it so that you can see it

Comment: The `breakpoint` which I mentioned won't let you render the template. It will stop the code right before it renders. So you can inspect in the console(where you type `runserver`) what is going on.

Comment: No! I mean even the `teacher_type` field which has nothing to do with conversion also can't be rendered to template

Comment: Did you try the breakpoint?

Comment: Wait! I never use it before. Now i'm looking on how to use breakpoint

Comment: I tried breakpoint() and it shows nothing

Comment: So whenever you type `context["teacher_info"]`it shows nothing? That means that your queryset is not returning any results. Use the administration platform to add some records first and try again, then it should work. If the admin works, then you have a problem in your form. Please update the question further after you do that.

Comment: ok let me try it